# Is automapper preventing lazy loading with EF?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, automapper

I have been using an AutoMapper and it seems that it gets me all the child entities (even if I don't specify them in "Include()" clause). Is there any way how to make lazy loading possible and get child properties only if I specify them.

Thank you,

Jakub

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After mapping you will have mapped object without any references to source entity (which holds database context for lazy loading). Only property values are copied to destination entity. So *you will not be able to do any lazy-loading without source entity*.

Actually lazy loading works just fine for you - and it's occur during mapping process. You specified mappings for lazy-loaded properties of your entity, and mapper tries to get those values. That results in lazy-loading all navigation properties which you have configured for mapping. This is very inefficient. To disable lazy-loading during mapping you can ignore navigation properties in mapping configuration. E.g. if you have customer with lazy-loaded orders:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
      .ForMember(s => s.Orders, m => m.Ignore());
```

Or remove `Orders` property from your destination entity `CustomerDto`. If you need to have `CustomerDto` instance with orders inside, then best option is to do eager loading of orders, to avoid additional queries.

Comment: Hello, yes that is the best approach I reckon. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to define your mapping objects according to your need. In the mapping object define only the needed child entities.Let's say some DTOs like this mapping in to the `Person` entity in the domain.

```
class PersonDto
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public PersonLiteDto Parent{get; set;}
}

class PersonLiteDto
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  //no navigation properties here..
}
```

Comment: I agree, automappers cache makes it really hard if you want to switch from de normal to the light and back again. you need to start using Mapper.Reset() and do all your mappings again. This is a better solution, although an even better one would be for automapper not to cause these problems in the first place.

Comment: better to make PersonDto inherit from PersonLiteDto