# AutoMapper binding issues with Entity Framework mapping

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper as an ORM in application with Entity Framework v6.

My problem statement is that if I executes a single query via LINQ to Entities on any single entity and maps entity data via AutoMapper with DTO, many other queries will be executed at the same time while data binding.

Kindly anyone let me know, how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Remember, AutoMapper just looks at the destination type and will map matching properties from the source type. If you don't want some properties to be mapped lazily, you have several options:

1. Remove the properties from the destination model
2. Use Include to eagerly fetch properties
3. Use LINQ projection in AutoMapper (ProjectTo) to force EF to use the Select LINQ projection to grab whatever data it needs to based on the source type

Comment: Here is the culprit of my code, which runs an extra query to map its attribute via lazy loading entities

`.ForMember(net => net.PropertyName, dto => dto.MapFrom(d => d.SRM_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.PROPERTY_NAME));
.ForMember(net => net.SystemName, dto => dto.MapFrom(d => d.SRM_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.SYSTEM_NAME));`

To map the navigation property attribute it runs a query for each record. Secondly the select query contains all the other table columns along with SYSTEM_NAME and PROPERTY_NAME

Is there any solution 1) single column query or single query to map all navigation properties.

Comment: Yes, you can use any of the solutions I laid out. Any one of those would fix the lazy loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may happens due to the lazy loading enabled.

Read this answer :

[Is automapper preventing lazy loading with EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825956/is-automapper-preventing-lazy-loading-with-ef)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes lazy loading is enabled in my entity model. I've enabled it purposely because I also need to load the reference tables as well. But I'm worried about the execution of same queries for reference tables multiple times. Executions are depends upon the number of main table records.

Comment: Can you provide us some examples of the queries ? Do you mean that you worried about circular reference something like : Parent>Child>Parent ?