# C# Automapper 6.1.1 - Collection/List destination properties loses values Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper, automapper-6

I have a problem when mapping collections with Automapper 6 and I can't find a solution. In the `updatedArticle` object below I have the old `Created` and `Updated` values left after mapping since they do not exist on the view model. However the values for `Created` and `Updated` in Descriptions are lost. The values that do come in via the view model are all updated correctly. What am I doing wrong? Automapper also loses Entity Framework 6 mapping for Article since those values are lost as well.

Controller method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateArticle(ArticleViewModel articleVm)
{
    Article articleOriginal = await iArticleRepository.GetAsync(articleVm.Id);
    Article updatedArticle = Mapper.Map<ArticleViewModel, Article>(articleVm, articleOriginal);
    return Ok();
}
```

Mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Created, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.Updated, opt => opt.Ignore());

    cfg.CreateMap<DescriptionViewModel, Description>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Created, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.Updated, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.ArticleId, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(x => x.Article, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Viewmodels:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DescriptionViewModel> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class DescriptionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class Article : IEntity<int>
{
    public Article()
    {
        Descriptions = new List<Description>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Description: IEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Heading { get; set; }

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved it after two days frustration. Installed AutoMapper.Collection from https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper.Collection
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework
```

All I had to change was `cfg.AddCollectionMappers();` and `EqualityComparison`. Example:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

    cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkPrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<DbContext>>();

    cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
        .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);

    cfg.CreateMap<DescriptionViewModel, Description>(MemberList.Source)
        .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
}
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I installed both the packages but using AddCollectionMappers() is throwing error. It doesn't recognize this. It says 'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'AddCollectionMappers'. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Oops.. Such a silly mistake. Installed it in some other project.

Comment: For some reason when I try to add the "AddCollectionMappers" it doesn't recognize it. I'm using Collection v4.0.0 and Automapper v7.0.1.

I did install it in the appropriate project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this without lazy loading? I had some issues with EF Lazy Loading and AutoMapper myself. First of all it is very inefficient.

See related 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826640/3122672).